# Mobile specific data transfer from Android mobile to a cloud

Tags: c#, android, cloud

I'm trying to develop a Android app which transfers mobile specific information like Text messages or Files from any Android mobile to a cloud. Can I know the process of data transmission from an Android device to a cloud. As a developer how can I proceed and integrate it with cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about using cloud database providers for your android application and not setup up or your own cloud database, you have to be specific what cloud database provider(s) that you are interesting in.

I suggest you to try Dropbox. Dropbox has a very easy to use set of APIs.

- Drop-ins: you do not have to do anything (component base)
- Sync Api: very easy to use and pretty much handle everything for you.
- core API: more flexible, since it is designed for server, you have to write your own nano http server to handle oauth2 authentication's url redirection or your users have to copy "authorization codes" manually from browser.

I suggest you use Sync Api.

I am using sync API for my Android App (EPass PM) and use core API with nano http server to handle OAuth2 for desktop version.

Here is the link to Dropbox api
https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
So by using sync api methods, can I be able to send my mobile specific data like Text messages of my mobile or files to Dropbox storage?